# How to remove last separator from html

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a simple question hoping someone can guide me the right way.

[image]

I just want to know how to remove the last separator after Taiwanese.

Here's my html ruby code.

```
<div class="well">
  <h4>Tags</h4>
  <% @food.categories.each do |category| %>
    <%= category.name %>
    <% if @food.categories.count > 1 %>
      |
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Please and thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative you can emit separators *before* category, except the first one.

```
<% @food.categories.each_with_index do |category, idx| %>
  <% if idx > 0 %>
    |
  <% end %>
  <%= category.name %>
<% end %>
```

Or even simpler

```
<%= @food.categories.map(&:name).join(' | ') %>
```

Comment: Can you explain the even simpler method? I can't get it to work. Does that go inside the loop?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @BrianLau: no, that goes _instead_ of the loop. Try that in a console, for example. You'll see what it does.

Comment: @BrianLau: ah, noticed a small mistake. Should work now

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
<% if @food.categories.count > 1 && @food.categories.last != category %>
  |
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<% @food.categories.each_with_index do |category, index| %>
  <% unless index.zero? %>
    |
  <% end %>    
  <%= category.name %>
<% end %>
```